# Hide a DIV if the post type is in a custom taxonomy term

Tags: wordpress, custom-taxonomy

I need to hide a DIV when my post type is in a taxonomy. Let's say that I've got the taxonomy the the slug "mostrar" with the terms "yes" and "no".

When the post type is in the taxonomy term "no" I want to hide a div.

I've tried this without success.

```
<?php if (!is_tax( 'mostrar', 'no' )) { ?>

    <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-5">

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Any ideas?

---

I've being trying this as well, no success:

```
<?php if ( has_term( 'mostrar', 'si' ) ) { ?>
         Yes
<?php } elseif ( has_term( 'mostrar', 'no' ) ) { ?>
         No
<?php } ?>
```

---

Update, the working code is:

```
<?php if (has_term('si','mostrar')) { ?>
        <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-5">

        </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if you want to show/hide this div after a request/post to the server or when the user is currently editing a form. In the latter case, you will probably need to use Javascript instead of PHP.

Comment: @probitaille, thanks for the reply. I have a DIV and I need to hide it when my post is in the term "no".

Comment: Your second example is backwards, you put the `term` first, then the `taxonomy`. `has_term( 'si', 'mostrar' )` is what it should be. Try that out. The documentation is pretty clear: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it's a typo based on swapping the arguments in the `has_term()` function

Answer (score 0):

use `has_term()` like:

```
has_term('no')
```

So your code can be written as

```
<?php if (!has_term('no')) { ?>

    <div id="sidebar" class="col-sm-5">

    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope that works for you.

Comment: This will not work. `has_term` does not accept an array to include the term and the taxonomy. `is_tax` will not work for this case either, as that is used for an archive.

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working. @disinfor is right (has_term('si','mostrar')) is the correct one.